# How to ensure my self executing block is executed and ready for use in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 script files

File1.js

```
var module = com.utils.createNamespace('com.PDP.OrderMySampleTemplate');
(function(OrderMySampleTemplate) {
    .....
})(module);
```

File2.js

```
var module = com.utils.createNamespace('com.PDP.OrderMySample');
(function($,m,OrderMySample,OrderMySampleTemplate) {
    ......
})(jquery,mustache,module,com.PDP.OrderMySampleTemplate);
```

and in my JSP i make a call to the init method defined in File2

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() { com.PDP.OrderMySample.init(); } );
</script>
```

I get a JS error saying the variables com.PDP.OrderMySample is not defined.
Both file1,file2 and the JSP which invokes them are downloaded as Ajax response
My question here is how can i ensure that all my JS files are downloaded and the self executing blocks are executed so that I can make use of those variables to invoke the function inside it

Comment: When you post code, do not use tabs and you need a line break before the code block.

Comment: `com.PDP.OrderMySampleTemplate`? Are you writing Java or JavaScript? (yes, I know the answer, but I'd advise you to write JavaScript using a *JavaScript* approach, rather than forcing Java into the equation). Regardless, [module loaders](http://requirejs.org/) were invented for reasons similar to this, you might want to look into using these rather than reinventing the wheel.